# Chrome headless - Process showing a "--service-request-channel-token". What is it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

Running some tests using Chrome Headless, I noticed an increase of sub-processes launched by Chrome, that contains a "--service-request-channel-token" parameter, followed by a different number (some kind of uuid).

Here's an example:

> /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --disable-background-timer-throttling --use-gl=swiftshader-webgl --field-trial-handle=13269729711699588785,2304692341994267143,131072 --disable-databases --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --headless --enable-crash-reporter --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=1076358315904091895 --renderer-client-id=12373 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101

I tried to search about this parameter but was unlucky.